# Why can constructor with single parameter be invoked without any arguments at all?

Tags: groovy

```
class Foo {
  public Foo(String s) {}
}
print new Foo()
```

Why does this code work?

If I declare constructor with parameter of primitive type the script fails.

Comment: Added a bit to my answer, as I got clarification from the core groovy developers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy will do its best to do what you asked it to do.  When you call `new Foo()`, it matches the call to calling `new Foo( null )` as there is a constructor that can take a `null` value.

If you make the constructor take a primitive type, then this cannot be `null`, so Groovy throws a `Could not find matching constructor for: Foo()` exception as you have seen.

It does the same with methods, so this:

```
class Test {
  String name
  
  Test( String s ) {
    this.name = s ?: 'tim'
  }
  
  void a( String prefix ) {
    prefix = prefix ?: 'Hello'
    println "$prefix $name"
  }
}

new Test().a()
```

prints `Hello tim` (as both constructor and method are called with a null parameter)

wheras:

```
new Test( 'Max' ).a( 'Hola' )
```

prints `Hola Max`

### Clarification

I [asked on the Groovy User mailing list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Calling-constructor-Object-with-no-params-td5712008.html), and got the following response:

> This is valid for any method call (not only constructors) and I (as well as others) really dislike this "feature" (because it's very error prone) so it will probably disappear in Groovy 3. Also, it's not supported by static compilation :)

So there, it works (for now), but don't rely on it :-)

Comment: It should be noted that I cannot find this documented anywhere, so would be **extremely** hesitant about exploiting it in any code (as I guess things without documentation are more likely to vanish in later versions of Groovy)